# Convert a .PEM certificate to .PFX programmatically using OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, pfx, x509certificate2, pem, pkcs#12

I've got a [.PEM file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_filename_extensions) that I want to convert to a PKCS12 file (PFX), and I know I can easily accomplish this using the following `openssl` command:

> ```
> Create a PKCS#12 file:
>
>  openssl pkcs12 -export -in file.pem -out file.p12 -name "My Certificate"
> ```

Which is great, but I'd like to do this programmatically using [OpenSSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) calls. Unfortunately, documentation for OpenSSL is less than ideal.

I've looked into doing this using other libraries:

Using .NET: I can create a X509Certificate2 object from a PEM file, but this only grabs the first certificate and ignores any intermediate CA's in the PEM file.

Using [Mentalis.org](http://mentalis.org) Security Library: I can create a Certificate object from a PEM file, but I see the following in the documentation:

> Remarks 
>   This implementation only reads
>   certificates from PEM files. It does
>   not read the private key from the
>   certificate file, if one is present.

So, that doesn't help me. I need that private key too.

I basically need to recreate the OpenSSL command line tool operation for going PEM>PFX, but in code.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You could use [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) (assuming C#, because you mentioned .NET).

Let's say `localhost.pem` here contains both the certificate and the private key, something like this should work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;

namespace TestApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("localhost.pem");
            IPasswordFinder passwordFinder = new PasswordStore("testtest".ToCharArray());
            PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(sr, passwordFinder);


            Pkcs12Store store = new Pkcs12StoreBuilder().Build();
            X509CertificateEntry[] chain = new X509CertificateEntry[1];
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair privKey = null;

            object o;
            while ((o = pemReader.ReadObject()) != null)
            {
                if (o is X509Certificate)
                {
                    chain[0] = new X509CertificateEntry((X509Certificate)o);
                }
                else if (o is AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)
                {
                    privKey = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)o;
                }
            }

            store.SetKeyEntry("test", new AsymmetricKeyEntry(privKey.Private), chain);
            FileStream p12file = File.Create("localhost.p12");
            store.Save(p12file, "testtest".ToCharArray(), new SecureRandom());
            p12file.Close();
        }
    }

    class PasswordStore : IPasswordFinder
    {
        private char[] password;

        public PasswordStore(
                    char[] password)
        {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public char[] GetPassword()
        {
            return (char[])password.Clone();
        }

    }
}
```

You'll probably need something a bit more subtle for the `IPasswordFinder` and if you want to handle certificate chains correctly.
For more advanced features, you may be able to find more details in the [BouncyCastle examples](http://www.bouncycastle.org/viewcvs/viewcvs.cgi/csharp/crypto/test/).