# Programmatic way of using .pfx (pkcs12) file instead of .pem file for establishing SSL connection

Tags: c++, c, openssl, pfx, pkcs#12

Until now, we are using a `.pem` file and we are able to establish an SSL connection (just for reference, below code):

```
ASSERT(true == ::SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(
         m_Attribute.m_pContext, certificateFileName.c_str(), SSL_FILETYPE_PEM),
       "Unable to use certificate file.");

ASSERT(true == ::SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(
         m_Attribute.m_pContext, certificateFileName.c_str(), SSL_FILETYPE_PEM),
       "Unable to load private key file.");

::SSL_CTX_set_options(m_Attribute.m_pContext, g_SSLChoice[version].m_Negotiation);

// ... some more relevant code

ASSERT(true == ::SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(m_pSSL, hostName.c_str()),
       "Cannot enable server name indication for " + hostName);

{
  int result = ::SSL_connect(m_pSSL);
  ASSERT(result == 1, "Cannot build an SSL connection, error = " +
      Util::Convert::to_string(::SSL_get_error(m_pSSL, result)));
}
```

However now the requirement has changed and we have to use `.pfx` file. In OpenSSL, I couldn't find an option/function for using the same.

Have searched many threads in SO and various forums like:
[Converting .PFX to .PEM programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677225/converting-pfx-to-pem-programmatically)
[Convert a .PEM certificate to .PFX programmatically using OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097642/convert-a-pem-certificate-to-pfx-programmatically-using-openssl)
[Converting pfx to pem using openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413646/converting-pfx-to-pem-using-openssl)
... and few others.

But couldn't find a way to convert `.pfx` to `.pem` programmatically in C/C++ with Linux.
Is there any readily available OpenSSL API which supports this? (e.g. for .pem we have a constant `SSL_FILETYPE_PEM`]

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to use convertions with standard C99/ANSI libs.
You can alternatively try to use system() or popen() to call sys function, like OpenSSL.

> $ openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -out cert.pem

Comment: I find [this Windows based program](https://github.com/michaelmotes/PKCS12toPEM/blob/master/PKCS12toPEM/PKCS12toPEM.cpp) in one of the above links. What is your view on that? (Also [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549459/extracting-client-certificate-private-key-from-p12-file)).

Comment: I think using openssl API can be an alternative. Anyway, if you dont want to use it statically linked, you can optionally go for dynamic links. Am I beeing helpful ?

Comment: Actually this issue is in a mobile platform for changing .pfx file now and then. I hope that the `system()` command would work across all the mobile and desktop platforms. Which OpenSSL API are you referring to, is it a function ?

Comment: You can only use 1 single compilation through CrossPlataforms?
I mean, if you use compilation directives, you can avoid incompatibilities, like using -DANDROID or something like that (if using gcc) to choose what openssl call to use, depending on what OS are you running.